# How to properly map entities in a business layer?

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper

I'm working in a multiple layers application ( basically web, data, business).
I'm trying to properly pass objects between the layers so, for the web, I used AutoMapper to pass a DTO to my business layer.
Everything went ok because I'm in the web layer which has the Startup.cs so I could add the following `services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));` in `ConfigureServices`.

Question is, can I do the same to map the Entity I retrieve from DB to a BusinessObject, in my Business layer that doesn't have the Startup.cs?

How do I configure AutoMapper in that case?

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));`, `params Type[] profileAssemblyMarkerTypes` is the types, it will loop the types in this assemply to find the `Profile`.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddAutoMapper(this IServiceCollection services, params Type[] profileAssemblyMarkerTypes)
        => AddAutoMapperClasses(services, null, profileAssemblyMarkerTypes.Select(t => t.GetTypeInfo().Assembly));
```

Not sure whether you add the profile for `DB to a BusinessObject` in web, data or business project, you just need to configure the type whose assemply contains the `profile` in web project.